# Django: filter first items, based on ForeignKey

Tags: python, django

Let's say I have this models (**mariaDB**):

```py
class MediaSeries(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)


class MediaFiles(models.Model):
    entryNr = models.IntegerField(default=0, help_text="number of episode")
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    serie = models.ForeignKey(MediaSeries, null=True,
                              on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT)
```

**MediaFiles** can be a single entry, or a part of a series. When it is a part of a series, it will have an unique **entryNr**.
The **entryNr** can start with any number, not only from **1**.

I need now a filter method to filter all Mediafiles entries, what is part of an series, but only the first entry.

For example I have this raw list:

```json
{"entryNr": 0, "name": "test a1", "serie": 0},
{"entryNr": 2, "name": "test b1", "serie": 1},
{"entryNr": 3, "name": "test b2", "serie": 1},
{"entryNr": 4, "name": "test b3", "serie": 1},
{"entryNr": 1, "name": "test c1", "serie": 2},
{"entryNr": 2, "name": "test b1", "serie": 2},
{"entryNr": 5, "name": "test d1", "serie": 3},
{"entryNr": 6, "name": "test d2", "serie": 3},
{"entryNr": 7, "name": "test d3", "serie": 3},
{"entryNr": 0, "name": "test e1", "serie": 0},
{"entryNr": 0, "name": "test f1", "serie": 0}
```

And the result I need should be:

```json
{"entryNr": 2, "name": "test b1", "serie": 1},
{"entryNr": 1, "name": "test c1", "serie": 2},
{"entryNr": 5, "name": "test d1", "serie": 3}
```

With my current view and filter class I can filter already everything what is part of an series:

```py
class MediaFilesFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    serie__isnull = filters.BooleanFilter(field_name='serie_id',
                                          lookup_expr='isnull')

    class Meta:
        model = MediaFiles
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'serie__isnull',]


class MediaFilesViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows media to be viewed.
    """
    queryset = MediaFiles.objects.all().order_by('name')
    serializer_class = MediaFilesSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend, OrderingFilter,
                       SearchFilter)
    filterset_class = MediaFilesFilter
```

But how can I filter all the first media entries within a series?

**Only as a info:** The hole logic I need to use later with the rest_framework, but this is not so relevant here I think.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use `raw` method for such a complex query:

```py
MediaFiles.objects.raw("""
SELECT *
FROM my_project_mediafiles mf
  INNER JOIN
    (
      SELECT serie_id, MIN(entryNr) minEntryNr
      FROM my_project_mediafiles
      GROUP BY serie_id
    ) min_tbl
  ON min_tbl.serie_id = mf.serie_id
WHERE mf.entryNr = minEntryNr
""")
```

**NOTE:** I'm not sure what your `MediaFiles` table name is, it should be "{project_name}_mediafiles"

Comment: Thank you! But is this compatible with other filters? I need a generic way where I can dynamical combine this selection with other filters.